# How can we create date of birth field using validation

Tags: javascript, html

How can we add validation in date of birth input field .
I create one input field of date of birth and in this field it's show like that 01/07/1997.
But I want to get when date of birth enter in field it's showing like that,
Xx/xx/1997. Only year want to show date and months not show.

I tried but not work.
Anyone please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242707/discussion-on-question-by-namrata-soni-how-can-we-create-date-of-birth-field-usi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and change the code as per your requirement changes-
I have updated here you just copy paste this code into following URL-http://jsfiddle.net/h9f46/84/

```
  function validate(date){
    var eighteenYearsAgo = moment().subtract(18, "years");
    var birthday = moment(date);
    var dateVar = new Date(birthday);
    if (!birthday.isValid()) {
        return "invalid date";    
    }
    else if (eighteenYearsAgo.isAfter(birthday)) {
        return "**/**/"+ dateVar.getFullYear().toString(); 
    }
    else {
        return "sorry, no";    
    }
}

jsprint(validate, "12/10/2000");
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks for sharing but when I enter date month and year it's show all but I want when I enter date month and year it show this format like that xx/xx/2002

Comment: Can u please help me out its very helpful and very thankful to you

Comment: Hope you got my point

Comment: please help me out

Comment: can you explain exact what you want? because my function validating DOB with proper date .

Comment: Can u please send me your  screen shot first after that I will explain properly

Comment: I want when I enter date I want this format xx/xx/2002. Date month year

Comment: I am still stuck on that please help me out

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBvAj.png

Comment: Yes right I want like this only thanks

Comment: Can you please share whole code in here it's very helpful for me

Comment: Because in this link I am not able to open

Comment: Please share the whole code

Comment: check code I have updated code in answer.

Comment: Can u please share your html code

Comment: Can u please do some changes in this link as well as http://jsfiddle.net/h9f46/84/

Comment: please check http://jsfiddle.net/s3Ld0zj2/

Comment: Yes thanks for sharing but I want when I enter date month year that it's show like that xx/xx/2002

Comment: Not after 2nd field

Comment: Same field I want when I enter date months year I want this type xx/xx/2002

Comment: Can u help me out on same field

Comment: Still not resolve issues